# How can we use tags/labels in service accounts in GCP like we've in IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm trying to use tags/labels feature in service accounts like we've in IAM but I'm not able to find such option in GCP. If there is any alternative to achieve that please do let me know that too.

I tried to look for the feature in service account section but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to add tags to a service account in the GCP.

Comment: Here's a list of all services that support labels in GCP. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support

Comment: Can you suggest ways to access service-account via tools like circleci . Actually I want key-value pair functionality

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct equivalent like tags/labels for service accounts like in AWS IAM. You can use IAM roles to assign permissions to service accounts. In GCP labels are restricted to Compute Engine instances, disks, etc but not to service accounts.

[Custom IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) can be created with conditions and give specific permissions and they can be assigned to the service accounts;  Alternatively you can use the [Metadata feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata) of the service account to store key-value pairs similar to Labels.